# Jquery Slider Pause on mouseover Resume on mouseout

Tags: jquery, hover, slideshow, resume

I have a jQuery code for a slideshow and want to modify it to show a pause on mouseover and to resume on mouseout. Here is the code.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.gslider = function (settings) {
    var config = {
      groupid: 0,
      speed: 3000
    };
    if (settings) $.extend(true, config, settings)

    this.each(function (i) {
      var $cont = $(this);
      var gallery = $(this).children();
      var length = gallery.length;
      var timer = 0;
      var counter = 1;

      if (length > 1) {
        for (n = 1; n < length; n++) {
          $cont.find(".c-" + n).hide();
        }
        $cont.find(".c-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * length + 1)).show();

        timer = setInterval(function () {
          play();
        }, config.speed);
      }

      function transitionTo(gallery, index) {
        if ((counter >= length) || (index >= length)) {
          counter = 1;
        } else {
          counter++;
        }

        $cont.find(".c-" + counter).fadeIn(300)
        if (length > 1) {
          $cont.find(".c-" + index).fadeOut(300);
        }
      }

      function play() {
        if (length > 1) transitionTo(gallery, counter);
      }
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: What is this..? How do I use this code..? Can you provide an online  demo..?

Comment: It's from a wordpress plugin
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/adrotate/
file directory /library/jquery.adrotate.dyngroup.js
I was directed to edit this file to achieve what I want